# DVD Drive detected by BIOS, but lost by Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, dvd

This Windows 8 computer has had this DVD Drive installed for 2 years.

Now it no longer shows up in Windows. Neither Device Manager nor Disk Manager can detect it. But the BIOS clearly shows it connecting and working.

The drive is a cheap iHAS 224 B.

I have had this issue once before and changed the SATA cable to a different port on the mainboard, and then it worked again. But if it's the SATA port, why can the BIOS detect the drive just fine?

This is an ASRock Z77 Extreme4 motherboard.

Any thoughts?

-- edit --

I plugged the drive into another SATA port - still nothing (might have been the original port on which this has happened before) - and then a third one, and now it suddenly works again... Usually, I'd guess the motherboard's SATA ports are dying on me one by one, but why does the BIOS see the drive then?

I'm still looking for an answer because I have the suspicion this will happen again.

In addition to the drive, I also use Daemon Tools Lite (a DVD drive emulator) to mount images - it could theoretically have something to do with that. But that drive was not set to the same drive letter, and switching drive letter did not bring the actual drive back. Also, I have an identical computer with the same hardware drive and Daemon Tools version, and that one has never had this issue before...

Just throwing out more details because this doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: Maybe you need a new driver?

Comment: You said that you didn't see it in Device Manager. Are there any `unknown` devices listed in there? Additionally, have you installed any driver updates lately via Windows Updates?

Comment: It's a generic drive - it never needed me to install a driver when I built the computer. No `unknown` devices - it just doesn't show up. I haven't installed Windows updates in a few months, so no driver overwrites, either.

Comment: Try updating the drivers for your SATA controller in Windows. If possible, [download them from ASRock's website](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z77%20Extreme4/?cat=Download&os=All) rather than via Windows Update.

Comment: The driver versions I have and those on the website match, so I have the newest drivers...

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about the drivers for your DVD drive or the drivers for your SATA controller?

Comment: The DVD drive has no specific drivers - just the basic generic Windows drivers. The SATA Controller drivers that are installed are the same version as those that are the most current on the ASRock website.

Comment: Does the drive work on a different motherboard/computer? Does the BIOS support UEFI? If so, does the drive show up if you enable legacy mode? If you boot into a portable linux distro or the Windows installer/recovery partition, is the drive accessible?

Comment: I haven't tried booting into a different OS yet, and I don't know what UEFI is. The drive itself is definitely working because it works now on a different SATA port. It's either the ports dying on me for some reason, or it's Windows messing up - likely something in the Registry - that's my guess at this time.